# How to get blocked SMS or MMS in android using query?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to get blocked SMS list in android(galaxy S8+).
i tried this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms?simple=true");
                //Log.d("TAG","reached");
                ContentResolver con=getContentResolver();
                if(con==null){
                    Log.d("TAG","contentResolver not exist");
                    return;
                }
                Cursor cursor = con.query(uri, null, "spam_report=?", new String[]{"1"},"date_sent DESC");
```

and this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms?simple=true");
                //Log.d("TAG","reached");
                ContentResolver con=getContentResolver();
                if(con==null){
                    Log.d("TAG","contentResolver not exist");
                    return;
                }
                Cursor cursor = con.query(uri, null, "locked=?", new String[]{"1"},"date_sent DESC");
```

The results of this codes doesn't give me the result I want.
How to get blocked Message(MMS or SMS)!!

Comment: Please indicate what the specific code does differently than what you expect. Add an example of expected output / behavior and actually executed output / behavior.

Comment: @MarcoSacchi the both code's output was null. i expected output was more than 200 blocked Message(SMS) (because my phone has more than 200 blocked message).
i want blocked Message URI or can retrieve query.